# Apply \only to environment that contains listing

Tags: beamer, overlays

I cannot find a way to apply `\only<n>{content}` to a whole itemize environment.

My first approach was:

```latex
\only<1>{\begin{itemize}
    \item A
\end{itemize}}
```

But I get multiple error messages at compile time.
I have also tried multiple variations found on the web. But I cannot find a way of hide (not occupying space) the whole list.

---

### EDIT:

Here a minimum non-working example, after reading the comment of @Schrödinger's cat I realized that the problem arises when I use the lstMakeShortInline, in this case, `|First|`. Without it, it works.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily]|
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \column{0.55\textwidth}
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \only<1>{
      \begin{itemize}
      \item My code: |First|
      \end{itemize}
    }
    \only<2>{
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Second
      \end{itemize}
    }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a complete example that produces the error. I can't reproduce the problem. `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
\only<1>{\begin{itemize}
    \item A
\end{itemize}}
\pause
\only<2>{\begin{itemize}
    \item B
\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}` works fine.

Comment: Please change your title to reflect the real problem between `\only` and the `listing` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onlyenv` environment instead of the `\only` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily]|
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \column{0.55\textwidth}
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1>
      \begin{itemize}
      \item My code: |First|
      \end{itemize}      
    \end{onlyenv}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Second
      \end{itemize}
    \end{onlyenv}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't we just add `<2>` to itemize directly?

Comment: @daleif This is not the purpose of the original question: "How to apply overlay `\only` to a whole itemize environment?"

Comment: My reason for asking is if the OP is not aware of this option. Many users never comes past the first few constructions they learn

Comment: @daleif Add `<x>` to itemize acts like `\visible` not like `\only`...

Comment: I was (even after reading a whole lot) not aware of the `\onlyenv` environment, I will try it and come back.

Comment: it works perfect! thanks for sharing!